# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a complex, non-symmetric matrix using CUDA

Tags: cuda, linear-algebra, gpu

How do I use the CUDA cuSOLVER to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a dense, (double precision) complex, non-symmetric matrix?

Looking at the documentation, there are CUDA [routines](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#cuds-lt-t-gt-syevd) and [example code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#sygvd-example1) for solving a dense symmetric matrix, using 'syevd'.  I've come across another GPU-enabled package, [MAGMA](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/software/), which has the relevant function ([magma_zgeev](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/projectsfiles/magma/doxygen/group__magma__geev.html#gab62fcecc19de68e6ad9d9822b16006eb)).

Is it possible to find these eigenvalues/vectors using plain CUDA (SDK v8), or do I need an alternate library like MAGMA?

Comment: Is it a normal matrix? I ask to know if it is diagonalizable.

Comment: Did you find anything so far?

Comment: I have not found anything so far.

Answer (score 1):

As of the CUDA 11 release, cuSolver continues to offer only routines for obtaining the eigenvalues of symmetric matrices. There are no non-symmetric eigensolvers in cuSolver.